# Длинный Питон. Нужна формула

Tags: c#

После того, как Мартышка и Попугай досконально исследовали длину Удава, им стало очень скучно. Тут Слонёнок вспомнил, что в лесу живет ещё Питон, которого тоже можно измерять! Друзья сразу же отправились на его поиски.

Питон, как и Удав, тоже целый, поэтому его нельзя мерить половинками. Измерив Питона, Мартышка и Попугай узнали, что в Питоне помещается n целых Попугаев или m целых Мартышек. Обрадованная Мартышка убежала сообщить полученный результат Слонёнку. Когда она ушла, Попугая заинтересовал следующий вопрос: а сколько раз он помещается в одной Мартышке?

Так как Мартышка убежала, и измерить её он не может, Попугай решил попытаться выяснить, сколько целых Попугаев может поместиться в одной Мартышке, используя результаты измерения Питона. По заданным **n** и **m** выясните, какое минимальное и максимальное число целых Попугаев может помещаться в одной Мартышке.

**Входные данные**

Во входном файле заданы два целых числа n и m, каждое на своей строке — количество Попугаев и Мартышек в Питоне, соответственно (1 ≤ **n**, **m** ≤ 10^9).

**Выходные данные**

В выходной файл выведите два числа — минимальное и максимальное количество целых Попугае в одной Мартышке.

Comment: _Питон, как и Удав, тоже целый, поэтому его нельзя мерить половинками_ - а нифига! Длина удава - 38 попугаев и одно попугайское крылышко.

Comment: @XOOTO, обратите внимание на обновленный ответ. Задача оказалась несколько сложнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть питон имеет длину `x`, попугай — `y`, мартышка — `z`.

Пока не обращаем внимание на целочисленность операций, записываем из условия:

```
n = x / y
m = x / z
```

отсюда не сложно выразить:

```
r = z / y = n / m
```

Теперь вспоминаем, что деление у нас целочисленное и фактическая длина питона в попугаях лежит в интервале `[n; n+1)`, а в мартышках — в интервале `[m; m+1)`.

Таким образом, пользуясь свойствами обыкновенных дробей, устанавливаем, что наименьшее возможное количество попугаев в мартышке (строго) больше `n / (m+1)`, а наименьшее возможное — (строго) меньше `(n+1) / m`.

Ваша задача сводится к отысканию этих двух чисел.

Например, если на входе у нас `n = 10` и `m = 3`, то `10 / 4 = 2.5 < r < 11 / 3 = 3.667`, т. е. результат `2 3` (`2` всё же может быть: `r=2.6 > 2.5`, но в целых это `r=2`).

Или, если `n = 499` и `m = 5`, то `499 / 6 = 83.167 < r < 500 / 5 = 100`, т. е. результат `83 99` (`100`, понятно, быть не может).

Таким образом, окончательно: `Floor(n/(m+1)) <= r < Ceiling((n+1)/m)` или `Floor(n/(m+1)) <= r <= Ceiling((n+1)/m)-1`, вот эти две границы и пишите в ответ.

Здесь `Floor` — округление в вниз, а `Ceiling` — округление вверх.